# Sector disconnection in Type III von Neumann algebras?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am considering the Hilbert space $H$ built as the infinite tensor product of separable Hilbert spaces $H_\alpha, \alpha$ in some countable or uncountable infinite set. $H$ is non separable and the operators on $H$ form a type III vN algebra.

JvN showed that $H$ breaks down into an uncountable set of separable subspaces, all orthogonal with one another - let's call them sectors. Two vectors of $H$ built as the infinite tensor products of one vector in each $H_\alpha$ are in the same sector if they differ only by a finite number of vectors in the tensor product.

I have the feeling that there is a theorem that says that *bounded* operators on $H$ do not connect different sectors. I have number of examples but can't find a general proof of that. Is this a well known theorem in operator algebras? (I am a physicist, not an expert in operator algebras). Or is it wrong?

Comment: There are several things that are unclear/vague in this definition. First, for the usual definition of infinite tensor products you need "pointed" Hilbert spaces, i.e., Hilbert spaces with a distinguished unit vector $\xi_\alpha$. If you mean another construction, you should specify it. Second, the infinite tensor product is not necessarily non-separable. Third, the bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space form a type I factor and not a type III von Neumann algebra. One can get type III factors as ITP factors, but they will not be all of $B(H)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. Here are attempts to answer your 3 points

Comment: 1) I understand the distinguished unit vector is the infinite tensor product of one unit vector in each elementary $H_\alpha$. Picking this set of elementary unit vectors amounts to selecting a 'sector', and I understand that this is what JvN calls 'incomplete infinite tensor product ' as  opposed to the complete one that includes all choices of distinguished unit vectors.

Comment: 2) With this said the 'incomplete' product can be separable - while the complete can't: take the simplest possible example where $H_\alpha$ be the 2D complex vector space and take $\alpha$ to run over the integers. The dimension of the resulting $H$ has the power of continuum and so there is no countable basis dense in it - so it is non-separable.

Comment: 3) This sounds like being my point - considering the  operators on the complete infinite tensor product, all won't be of $B(H)$. And so the theorem I'm looking for would be that operators in $B(H)$ do not map vectors in a given incomplete tensor product to vectors in a different incomplete tensor product. And that operators who do are not in $B(H)$. Does such a theorem exist? If so do you have any reference?

Comment: I still don't follow. I really think you should include the definition of infinite tensor product you're using into your question.

Comment: I am using the definition of chapter 3 of JvN's _on infinite direct products_ (available at http://archive.numdam.org/article/CM_1939__6__1_0.pdf). The notion of pointed Hilbert space ('incomplete tensor product ') with a distinguished unit vector is introduced right after in Chap 4, as a consequence of theorem VIII. If that helps, I am still looking for a hint about bounded operators being able or not to map vectors in different such incomplete tensor product spaces.